# Jdbc Spring at Property 'dataSource' is required or NullPointer

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

When I run `compile()` after the `mapRow` is done. The error gives me `Property 'dataSource' is required`. I have this on my xml

```
<bean id="ProcedureRepository" class="mypackage.ProcedureRepository">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

My java `ProcedureRepository`

```
private DataSource dataSource;

@Resource
@Qualifier("dataSource")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public String searchCode(String code){
    new SeachCode(dataSource).execute(code);
    return code;
}
```

My SeachCode

```
public class SearchCode extends StoredProcedure{
public SearchCode(DataSource dataSource) {
    super(dataSource, "MYPROC");
...

compile();
```

It happens when I call this:

```
ProcedureRepository procedureRepository = new ProcedureRepository();
procedureRepository.searchCode(parameters.code);
```

I don't know where I'm missing, i tried to add new bean in my xml, but no success, same to add new `setDataSource` at `SearchCode`

Comment: Don't create a new instance yourself. Use the bean from the context.

Answer (score 0):

When you creating your repository using `new`, you just getting an object not managed by Spring container. If you want to get a Spring bean, which has all dependencies injected by Spring, you can get it from Spring application context.
For example:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("path to spring app context xml file)");    
ProcedureRepository repo= (ProcedureRepository) applicationContext.getBean("ProcedureRepository");
repo.searchCode(parameters.code)
```

[Here](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-creating-a-spring-application.html) you can read more about getting beans from Spring app context.

Comment: Is this the only way I can do that? What if I don't want to use the path? My web.xml already on context.

Comment: So if it is a webapp, spring context shoulb be initialized during startup by using ContextLoaderListener defined in your web.xml. In this case you can create some kind of service, which will be using you repository, or controller. Just define it in your application context and set repository as a dependency using setter or constructor injection.